# How to simulate WebSocket failure on a macOS browser?

Tags: macos, firewall, debug, websocket

I often deal with WebSocket failures, and debugging fixes is hard because I have not found a good way to simulate them. A lot of Linux tools are no longer available because macOS has now transitioned into using `pf` (the way I understand it; I'm a beginner at all this).

I've tried the native firewall, which doesn't seem to have enough control to block browser WebSockets only, and [murus](https://murusfirewall.com/), which can probably do the trick, but I haven't been able to.

Are there any known ways to simulate WebSocket failures in a browser in order to debug fallbacks, etc?

Comment: Have a look at burp suite: https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload It can do several things, but I am not sure if it's the right tool.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out

Comment: @davidbaumann That worked! If you want to write it up as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burp suite is the ultimate proxy to intercept and manipulate any connection that can use a proxy (socks/http/https...).

[image: Burp suite]